# Trouble detecting Firebase connection status in Swift app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble with detecting the Firebase connection status with my Swift app.  As soon as my view controller launches it immediately displays and alertView showing my connection status is down.  It does this every time regardless of what the status actually is when the app starts.  Once the app is started the connection status is reliably reported.  Even when I switch to another view controller and back to the original one it doesn't report the connection as down again.  It only happens when the app first launches.  Here is the code where I have implemented my connection status detection in the viewDidLoad method.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    //Do these things once when the app first starts up
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    setMapInitialState()

    let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(".info/connected")
    connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

        let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool
        if connected != nil && connected! {
            self.showAlertView("Alert", message: "Connection to server restored - all pending catches will be updated")
            self.refreshCatches()
        } else {
            self.showAlertView("Alert", message: "Connection to server lost - catches by others may not be up to date")
        }

    })

}
```

Answer (score 6):

My preferred method to handle this was to implement a shared instance which tracked the connection status. I had a `isConnected` boolean which would toggle between true and false depending on the `.info/connected` value, but I think it's also important to have another boolean, `hasConnected`.

`hasConnected` instantiates with `false`, and isn't changed unless we received a connected result. This means when the app is first reporting it's disconnected results, you can check the `hasConnected` boolean to determine if it's actually ever connected yet. You may want to simply disable your connection alerts until `hasConnected` is `true`.

```
let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(".info/connected")
connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (connected) in
    if let boolean = connected.value as? Bool where boolean == true {
        print("connected")
        self.hasConnected = true
        self.isConnected = true
    } else {
        print("disconnected")
        self.isConnected = false
    }
})
```

Let me know if there's anything you might want more information on.

Comment: so how the conditional works? like if hasConnected && isConnected {
// connected
} else {
//not connected
}

???